# Cannot display multiple Highcharts on a single page

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am trying to display 3 Highcharts-generated graphs on one page. I have loaded up the first two just fine but when I add the Javascript for the third all of them do not show. I have duplicated my code in this JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ricburton/bCU2E/

Any help or guidance would be really appreciated.

I have checked out this answer: [Manage multiple highchart charts in a single webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253590/manage-multiple-highchart-charts-in-a-single-webpage?rq=1)

And googled around a lot. I am sure it is my limited understanding of Javascript holding me back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you've missed } somewhere, here is what I see in firebug:

> missing } after function body

**edit**

you haven't closed last closure, add `});` at the end of code

I have also removed 2 closures and only one, see updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/bCU2E/2/

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax was wrong, updated; here is the correct [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/bCU2E/1/)