# How to add custom exporting button in highCharts?

Tags: highcharts, export

We are using highcharts in our application and I want to add an button next to print and export button. I do have working example in  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agorur/cCYZU/2/)

```
 var chart1;
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // Add Custom button to highchart
            chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container1',
                    shadow: true
                },
                title: { text: 'Sales' },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                                 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                },
                yAxis: { title: { text: '$'} },
                series: [{
                    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 
                           135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
                }],
                 exporting: {
                        buttons: {
                            'exportTo': {
                                _id: 'exportTo',
                                symbol: 'diamond',
                                x: -62,
                                symbolFill: '#B5C9DF',
                                hoverSymbolFill: '#779ABF',
                                onclick: function () {
                                    showDialog(this);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

            });


 var showDialog = function (selectedChart) {

                var modal = $("#myModal").modal();
                $('#btnSaveImage').click(function () {
                    saveChartInNas(selectedChart);
                    modal.modal('hide');
                });
            };
        });
```

We have lots of charts, on click of the chart I want to display a modal window and do some process on save button. Instead of creating the modal and exporting property settings for all charts in all the different pages I am wondering is it possible to **some kind of plugin or add on ?** If so, can someone show me how to achieve this.

I do not want to add exporting logic in all the pages.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manage multiple highchart charts in a single webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253590/manage-multiple-highchart-charts-in-a-single-webpage)

Comment: Charts are available in different pages. How to write a common settings for all the charts in all the pages?

Answer (score 1):

```
exporting: {
                           filename: 'event-id-metadata-graph',
                            buttons: {
                                contextButton: {
                                    menuItems: [{
                                        text: 'Download PDF',
                                        onclick: function () {
                                            this.exportChart({
                                                type: 'application/pdf'
                                            });
                                        }
                                    }, {
                                        text: 'Print',
                                        onclick: function () {
                                                alert('Launch Print Table function')
                                        },
                                        separator: false
                                    }]
                                }
                            }
                        },
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are asking whether there is a way to set this up as some sort of default, instad of editing every chart definition ?

You should take a look at Highcharts.setOptions() http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.setOptions()
This allows you to set up defaults for all charts.