# Same configs in multiple Highcharts

Tags: extjs, highcharts, config

I have three highcharts used in EXTJS 4.1.1 application which almost use the **same configs.** 
Can I have something like

```
var config = {
// configurations
}

Ext.define('chartsA',{
    extend:'Ext.panel.Panel',
    items:[{
      xtype:'highcharts',
      chartConfig:{
         //  config defined above
         // customConfigs for the particluar chart (if any)
      }
    }]
});
```

Like this for the next two charts also.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: this will probably help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253590/manage-multiple-highchart-charts-in-a-single-webpage

Comment: I used a parent class and extended it for the other charts.