# Trying to iterate an array through mutliple highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, csv, highcharts

So I have a large amount of data that I need to display all stored in separate CSV files. So I created two charts just fine in highcharts, one line, one area, but instead of copying and pasting the function over and over again I was hoping I could just iterate through it like so:

```
var library = ['data/data.csv', 'data/attendanceGroup.csv'];
var libraryLength = library.length;
var area =['#attendanceRoom','#attendanceGroup'];
var i = 0;

function areaChart(){
$(function () { 
    $.get(library[i], function(csv) {
        $(area[i]).highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'area'
            },
            data: {
                csv: csv
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Attendance by Room'
            },          
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                text: null
                },
                minorTickInterval: 'auto'
            },

            legend:{
                align: 'left',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                floating: true        
            },
        });
    }); 
});
}

for (i = 0; i < libraryLength; i++){
areaChart();
}
```

I was looking at this [Manage multiple highchart charts in a single webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253590/manage-multiple-highchart-charts-in-a-single-webpage) using jQuery.extend() or Highcharts.setOptions but that sets options for each individual chart and then you just make them over and over again. I thought a better solution might be to just have the one function and then just re-run it for each individual chart especially since I'm pulling the data from .CSV files.

So is this possible? Or should I go with jQuery.extend()?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: This looks like a perfectly fine solution given the small/predictable differences between your individual charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just two things I would improve:

1. `$(function () { });` - I would encapsulate whole JS, not only part with AJAX and Highcharts:

   ```
   $(function () { 
     var library = ['data/data.csv', 'data/attendanceGroup.csv'];

     ...

     for (i = 0; i < libraryLength; i++){
         areaChart();
     }
   });
   ```
2. make `library[i]` and `area[i]` as arguments for `areaChart()`:

   ```
   $(function () { 
     var library = ['data/data.csv', 'data/attendanceGroup.csv'];

     ...

     function areaChart(lib, area){
       $.get(lib, function(csv) {
         $(area).highcharts({
           chart: {
             type: 'area'
           },
           data: {
             csv: csv
           }
         });
       });
     }

     for (i = 0; i < libraryLength; i++){
       areaChart(library[i], area[i]);
     }
   });
   ```

Of course, you can add more params to `areaChart` for example `type`, and pass on what kind of the chart should be rendered:

```
$(function () { 
    var library = ['data/data.csv', 'data/attendanceGroup.csv'];
    var types = ['line', 'area'];

    ...

    function areaChart(lib, area, type){
      $.get(lib, function(csv) {
        $(area).highcharts({
          chart: {
            type: type
          },
          data: {
            csv: csv
          }
        });
      });
    }

    for (i = 0; i < libraryLength; i++){
      areaChart(library[i], area[i], types[i]);
    }
});
```

Don't overdo with the params, no one likes to read 10params and control order etc. Instead you may consider passing one object param (renamed from `areaChart` to `myChart`):

```
myChart({
  lib: library[i], 
  area: area[i], 
  type: types[i]
});
```

And in `myChart()` method:

```
function myChart(options) {
    $.get(options.lib, function(csv) {
        $(options.area).highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: options.type
            },
            data: {
                csv: csv
            }
        });
    });
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why this change mattered but it did and know it works beautifully. Thank you for the improvements!

Comment: If something didn't work, then most probably #1 resolved your issue. It was a bit strange to wait for load event in function.